# How to format Date (2020-11-23T13:26:02.000Z) to Y-m-d h:i:s in laravel using Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have date data like this `2020-11-23T13:26:02.000Z`and i want to conver to format `Y-m-d h:i:s` = `2020-11-23 13:26:02` using Carbon in Laravel

Comment: $date = Carbon::parse($item['time']); $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Carbon::parse`:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2020-11-23T13:26:02.000Z')->toDateTimeString();

dd($date); // 2020-11-23 13:26:02
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
 You can do sth like it and then get the date in "Y-m-d h:i:s" format

```php
$date = new Carbon("2020-01-29T00:30:01.000Z");
/*
Carbon::__set_state(array(
   'date' => "2020-01-29 00:30:01",
   'timezone_type' => 2,
   'timezone' => "Z",
))
*/
```